# How to check if input is incorrect in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that takes some data from users and display their entered information back to them. I take date and time using following:

```
echo "Enter day:"
read day
echo "Enter time (hour):"
read hour

if [["$hour" -gt 24 || "$hour" -lt 1]] 
then
echo "Wrong data"
echo "Enter time (hour):"
read hour
fi
```

When I run this I get following enter:

```
./file1.sh: line 5: [[27: command not found
./file1.sh: line 5: 27: command not found
```

27 is the number I entered for hour.

Comment: Put a space after `[[` and before `]]`, like this: `[[ "$hour" -gt 24 || "$hour" -lt 1 ]] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space after `[[` and before `]]`.